# MySQL UPDATE query SHA512 MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: mysql, syntax, sha512

does anybody know why an INSERT with sha512 is working without any problem:

```
String query = " insert into user (username, password, surname, lastname, email, admin)"
            + " values (?, sha2(?, 512), ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    System.out.println("query: " + query);
    // create the java statement
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, newUser.getUsername());
    ps.setString(2, getPsw());
    ps.setString(3, newUser.getSurename());
    ps.setString(4, newUser.getLastname());
    ps.setString(5, newUser.getEmail());
......
......
```

and an UPDATE query not:

```
String query = "update user set password = sha2(?, 512) where id = "+getId()+")";
    System.out.println("query: " + query);
    // create the java statement
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, psw_edit);
```

I get the following MySQLSyntaxErrorException:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra closing brace `)` in your UPDATE code

Try changing it to

`String query = "update user set password = sha2(?, 512) where id = "+getId();`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw this after I posted it :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that mySQL have a problem with **password**. Possibly it notices **password** as a mySQL Keyword. The solution is to write it on this way: `password`

But still a better solution is to hash a password directly in JAVA. Even better to create a salted hash first.